# How to switch user in Centos

Tags: centos

I need command to known the command, which switch between users in command prompt. Im using CentOS 6.5 and Putty.  Does anybody know this command?
Thanks for help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about CentOS is more appropriate for the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: I agree, but it is handy if you are searching for this, instead of Linux, plus the majority of votes find this convenient too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command you're looking for is **su**.

Answer (score 30):

You can use su to change to another user:

```
su <username>
```

for more help with the su command, you can read the man page via the man command:

```
man su
```

Answer (score 3):

First use man to learn tutorial about su then implement.

```
man su
```

then use a below-mentioned command to switch between users.

### su [anyusername]

```
su root
password :
[root@localhost ~]$
```

##now enjoy your commands.